# Flask Appbuilder Run Error: "IndexError: list index out of range"

Tags: python, flask, flask-appbuilder

My views.py and models.py are as below:

**views.py:**

```
import calendar
from flask_appbuilder import ModelView
from flask_appbuilder.models.sqla.interface import SQLAInterface
from flask_appbuilder.charts.views import GroupByChartView
from flask_appbuilder.models.group import aggregate_count
from flask_appbuilder.widgets import FormHorizontalWidget, FormInlineWidget, FormVerticalWidget
from flask_babel import lazy_gettext as _

from app import db, appbuilder
from .models import DB, Table

class tableModelView(ModelView):
    datamodel = SQLAInterface(Table)
    list_columns = ['table_group.table_db_name', 'table_name', 'ddl']
    base_order = ['table_group.table_db_name', 'asc']
    show_fieldsets = [
            ('Summary', {'fields' : list_columns})
        ]
    add_fieldsets = [
            ('Summary', {'fields' : list_columns})
        ]
    edit_fieldsets = [
            ('Summary', {'fields' : list_columns})
        ]

class GroupModelView(ModelView):
    datamodel = SQLAInterface(DB)
    related_views = [tableModelView]


db.create_all()
appbuilder.add_view(GroupModelView, "List DBs",
                    icon="fa-folder-open-o", category="DB", category_icon='fa-envelope')
appbuilder.add_separator("Table")
appbuilder.add_view(tableModelView, "List Tables",
                    icon="fa-folder-open-o", category="Table", category_icon='fa-envelope')
```

**models.py:**

```
import datetime
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String, ForeignKey, Date
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship
from flask_appbuilder import Model

mindate = datetime.date(datetime.MINYEAR, 1, 1)

class DB(Model):
    db_name = Column(String(50), unique=True, primary_key=True, nullable=False)

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.name

class Table(Model):
    table_name = Column(String(100), primary_key=True)
    ddl = Column(String(16384), unique=True)

    table_db_name = Column(Integer, ForeignKey(DB.db_name), nullable=False)
    table_group = relationship("DB")

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.name
```

However, when I run it, it has this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "run.py", line 1, in <module>
    from app import app
  File "/Users/x0m00jk/Platform-Manager/app/__init__.py", line 28, in <module>
    from app import models, views
  File "/Users/x0m00jk/Platform-Manager/app/views.py", line 56, in <module>
    icon="fa-folder-open-o", category="DB", category_icon='fa-envelope')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_appbuilder/base.py", line 351, in add_view
    baseview = self._check_and_init(baseview)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_appbuilder/base.py", line 303, in _check_and_init
    baseview = baseview()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_appbuilder/views.py", line 451, in __init__
    super(ModelView, self).__init__(**kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_appbuilder/baseviews.py", line 631, in __init__
    super(BaseCRUDView, self).__init__(**kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_appbuilder/baseviews.py", line 398, in __init__
    self._init_properties()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_appbuilder/baseviews.py", line 696, in _init_properties
    self.list_columns = self.list_columns or [list_cols[0]]
IndexError: list index out of range
```